# Pushing into nested subdocument arrays in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a rather complex db:

```
var bookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    content: {
        page: [pageSchema]
    },
    //otherThings
});

//my book has pages
var pageSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        comments: [commentSchema]
    },
    {_id: false}
);

//comments have replies.
var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    comment: String,
    replies: [this]
});
```

I am trying to add a reply to a comment.

I have the ID of the comment to which I want to add the reply.

But how?

I tried:

```
Book.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
             'content.page.comments._id': ID    
            },
            {
            $push: {'content.page.$.comments.$.replies': myReply}    
            },
            function (err) {
                //...
            }
        )
```

But that is impossible because I cant use a positional($) more than once.

I'm trying to figure this one out for hours now.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Use simple way - `commentsSchema`

```
Comment.update({_id: ID}, {$push: {replies: myReply}}, function (err) {});
```

This will update comment model, and the book model will get updated too

Comment: This doesn't work.
even Comment.find({_id:ID}) doesn't return any documents. Even Comment.find({}) doesn't return any documents. I wish it worked. it seemed so nice!

Comment: You definitely have problems with registering models, it should return something

Comment: if `comment.find({})` doesnt return anything, how can they be stored in `books` schema? there must be some problem in your code. Can you check again?

Comment: Mind you, I am not keeping a reference of the comment in Page model. I am storing the actual document. therefore, there is no collection called Comment at all. So I'm not surprised it's not working.

Comment: Then register model and use it, its much easier